# How to use useFocusEffect hook to fetch data?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

I'm a newbie in React Native and have just upgraded to `react-navigation-5`

And I'm struggling to replace the old `listener` function with the new hook `useFocusEffect`

Here's the old function:

```
const loadTrips = useCallback(async() => {
        setError(null);
        setIsRefreshing(true);
        try {
            dispatch(tripActions.fetchTrip());
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
            setError(error.message);
        }
        setIsRefreshing(false);
    },[dispatch, setIsRefreshing, setError]);
*********************************************************
// This is the old function
    useEffect(() => {
        const willFocus = props.navigation.addListener(
            'willFocus',
            loadTrips
        );
        return () => {willFocus.remove();}
    },[loadTrips]);
*********************************************************

    useEffect(() => {
        setIsLoading(true);
        loadTrips().then(
            setIsLoading(false),
        );
    }, [dispatch, loadTrips])
```

**EDIT 1**

I tried to pass the `loadtrips` function to `useFocusEffect` but it shows error

```
useFocusEffect(loadTrips)
```

**PLEASE HELP**

[image: Error]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply pass in the `loadTrips` function to `useFocusEffect`

```
const loadTrips = useCallback(async() => {
        setError(null);
        setIsRefreshing(true);
        try {
            dispatch(tripActions.fetchTrip());
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
            setError(error.message);
        }
        setIsRefreshing(false);
    },[dispatch, setIsRefreshing, setError]);
useFocusEffect(useCallback(() => loadTrips(), [dispatch, setIsRefreshing, setError]));
```

Comment: Hey Shubham, thanks for the help. But it shows error when I try your way

Comment: Thanks for the update. However, when I try to add the ```myFunc``` into ```loadTrips``` like that, ```loadTrips``` would no longer be a ```Promise```. And since I use it as a ```Promise``` in the ```useEffect``` call ( bottom of my code shown in the question), it will show error : undefined as an object( evaluating ```loadTrips().then()``` ). And it did show error when I tried that

Comment: ok, there is another way around it then. Updating my answer for it